# Unity URP Material scripting

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, lighting, urp

I just started using URP in Unity for a game in progress. I'm doing a sort of sprites-in-3d thing, so I'm rendering some sprite sheets on quads. To do this, I create a Material with the sprite sheet and use tiling/offset to render the proper frame of animation by making a call like:

```
CombatMaterial?.SetTextureOffset("_BaseMap", new Vector2( (AnimationDefinitions[animationDefinition] % 16) * .0625f, CombatMaterial.mainTextureOffset.y));
```

I'm currently trying to add some feedback into my game for when characters use abilities or get hit by flickering the material. Because the base color starts at white and goes to black, that won't really work; the only other thing I seem to have available to me is emission, which looks great. Using a 0xAAAish color achieves the effect I'm looking for. I've been using the Feel Unity asset to do this, but I've also attempted using something like this:

```
CombatMaterial?.SetColor("_EmissionColor", Color.white);
```

The problem is, once I've set the `_EmissionColor`, the main texture offset no longer updates in game, thereby ruining all animations. If I change the texture offset manually through the inspector at runtime, animations don't work AND the `_EmissionColor` flickering stop working. If I mess around with the color of the `_BaseMap` in the inspector, `_EmissionColor` flickering starts working again.

Before I start diving into some unsightly color adjustments in an attempt to make this work again, I would love to know if I'm doing something that is simply unsupported by URP/Materials/whatever, or if there is some alternative to what I'm doing that's a little more straightforward.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After trying a bunch of random stuff, I don't have a "real" solution, but the game IS working how I want it to.

What worked for me was setting the `_EmissionColor` on the Material to (1,1,1). For some reason, when the `_EmissionColor` is set to (0,0,0) it's a black (ha) hole and won't accept future changes to the `_EmissionColor`. I assume this is some shader nonsense (with the base Lit Shader that URP uses) that I am clearly unfamiliar with.

Hopefully this helps anyone doing something as pointlessly against the grain as I am!